# Playing sounds in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I am playing a sound through javascript with this code

```
 var snd = new Audio("flip.mp3"); // buffers automatically when created
snd.play();
```

All is well, but I want to play the sound lots of times, so each time a user clicks on an object, the sound is played. This works for about 20 times, but then the sound doesn't play at all. Does anyone have any idea as to what the problem could be?

Comment: The browser probably got pissed off at being abused and threw in the towel.

Comment: I get the feeling that might be it...does anyone know how I can stop pissing of the browser?

Comment: *off. Joke: I was not aware browsers could piss, and I think it would be awkward to stop the pissing of the browser.

Comment: Are you creating a `new Audio()` every time?

Answer (score 2):

You should globally declare :

```
var snd = new Audio("flip.mp3");
```

Then call play in a function on click:

```
function playSound() {
    snd.play();
}
```